# customize two legends inside one graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I wanted to comment on the following doubt.

Using this code:

```
Plot<-data.frame(Age=c(0,0,0,0,0),Density=c(0,0,0,0,0),Sensitivity=c(0,0,0,0,0),inf=c(0,0,0,0,0),sup=c(0,0,0,0,0),tde=c(0,0,0,0,0))    
Plot[1,]<-c(1,1,0.857,0.793,0.904,0.00209834)
Plot[2,]<-c(1,2,0.771   ,0.74,0.799,0.00348286)
Plot[3,]<-c(1,3,0.763   ,0.717,0.804,0.00577784) 
Plot[4,]<-c(1,4,0.724   ,0.653,0.785,0.00504161)
Plot[5,]<-c(2,1,0.906,0.866,0.934,0.00365742)
Plot[6,]<-c(2,2,0.785   ,0.754,0.813,0.00440399)
Plot[7,]<-c(2,3,0.660,0.593,0.722,0.00542849)
Plot[8,]<-c(2,4,0.544,0.425,0.658,0.00433052)

     names(Plot)<-c("Age","Mammographyc density","Sensitivity","inf","sup","tde")
    Plot$Age<-c("50-59","50-59","50-59","50-59","60-69","60-69","60-69","60-69")
    Plot$Density<-c("Almost entirely fat","Scattered fibroglandular density","Heterogeneously dense","Extremely dense","Almost entirely fat","Scattered fibroglandular density","Heterogeneously dense","Extremely dense")    
levels(Plot$Age)<-c("50-59","60-69")
levels(Plot$Density)<-c("Almost entirely fat","Scattered fibroglandular density","Heterogeneously dense","Extremely dense")
pd <- position_dodge(0.2) # 
    Plot$Density <- reorder(Plot$Density, 1-Plot$Sensitivity)

ggplot(Plot, aes(x = Density, y = 100*Sensitivity, colour=Age)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = 100*inf, ymax = 100*sup), width = .1, position = pd) +
  geom_line(position = pd, aes(group = Age), linetype = c("dashed")) +
  geom_point(position = pd, size = 4)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),name = 'Sensitivity (%)',sec.axis = sec_axis(~./5,   name  = 'Breast cancer detection rate (per 1000 mammograms)', breaks = c(0,5,10,15,20),
                                                              labels = c('0‰',"5‰", '10‰', '15‰', '20‰')), limits = c(0,100)) +
   geom_line(position = pd, aes(x = Density, y = tde * 5000, colour = Age, group = Age), linetype = c("dashed"), data = Plot) +
  geom_point(shape=18,aes(x = Density, y = tde * 5000, colour = Age, group = Age), position = pd, size = 4) +
  theme_light() + 
 scale_color_manual(name="Age (years)",values = c("50-59"= "grey55", "60-69" = "grey15")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") + guides(colour = guide_legend(), size = guide_legend(),
                                         shape = guide_legend())
```

I have made the following graph,

[image: Graph]

in which the axis on the left is the scale of the circles and the axis on the right is the scale of the diamonds. The fact is that I would like to have a legend approximately like this:

[image: Legend]

But it is impossible for me, I have tried suggestions of other threads like `scale_shape` and different commands in `guides` but I have not got success. I just want to make clear the difference in what shape and color represent.

Would someone know how to help me?

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you *should* do is a panel plot to avoid the confusion of double axes:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Plot %>% 
  gather(measure, Result, Sensitivity, tde) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Density, y = Result, colour=Age)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = inf, ymax = sup), width = .1, position = pd,
                data = . %>% filter(measure == "Sensitivity")) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Age), position = pd, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_point(position = pd, size = 4)+
  # scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_wrap(~measure, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_light() + 
  scale_color_manual(name="Age (years)",values = c("50-59"= "grey55", "60-69" = "grey15")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

But to do what you asked, you problem is that you have only 1 non-positional aesthetic mapped so you cannot get more than one legend. To force a second legend, you need to add a second mapping. It can be a dummy mapping that has no effect, as below we map `alpha` but then manually scale both levels to 100%. This solution **is not advisable** because, as you have done in your example of a desired legend, it is easy to mix up the mappings and have your viz tell a lie by mislabeling which points are sensitivity and which are detection rate.

```
ggplot(Plot, aes(x = Density, y = 100*Sensitivity, colour=Age, alpha = Age)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = 100*inf, ymax = 100*sup), width = .1, position = pd) +
  geom_line(position = pd, aes(group = Age), linetype = c("dashed")) +
  geom_point(position = pd, size = 4)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),name = 'Sensitivity (%)',sec.axis = sec_axis(~./5,   name  = 'Breast cancer detection rate (per 1000 mammograms)', breaks = c(0,5,10,15,20),
                                                                                   labels = c('0‰',"5‰", '10‰', '15‰', '20‰')), limits = c(0,100)) +
  geom_line(position = pd, aes(x = Density, y = tde * 5000, colour = Age, group = Age), linetype = c("dashed"), data = Plot) +
  geom_point(shape=18,aes(x = Density, y = tde * 5000, colour = Age, group = Age), position = pd, size = 4) +
  theme_light() + 
  scale_color_manual(name="Age (years)",values = c("50-59"= "grey55", "60-69" = "grey15")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 1)) +
  guides(alpha = guide_legend("Sensitivity"),
         color = guide_legend("Detection Rate", override.aes = list(shape = 18))) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: I think the solution you propose is much better, thank you very much. Just one question, how can I change the label of that "tde"? Because I would really like it to put "Detection rate" and I can not call the variable like that.

Comment: Customizing facet labels is a bit complicated. What I do most often is rename the variable in the data frame before passing it to ggplot. To do it in the plot, you would add this argument into the `facet_wrap` call: `labeller = labeller(measure = c("Detection rate" = "tde", "Sensitivity" = "Sensitivity"))`